# Angular lifecycle onInit and onChanges with subscriptions

Tags: angular

I am passing some @Input props down from the parent and whenever my prop is updated, I want my component to update.

What I was doing is this:

```
@Input() variable;
@Input() variable2;

public deets;

constructor() { 
  this.details$ = this._sore.select("details") 
}

ngOnInit() { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (
    changes.variable && changes.variable.currentValue ||
    changes.variable2 && changes.variable2.currentValue
  ) {
    this.apiCall();
    this.subscribeMethod();
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.deets.unsubscribe();
}

subscribeMethod() {
  this.deets = this.details$.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) // this.action1()
  }
}

apiCall() {
  this._store.dispatch(new LoadDetailsAction);
}

action1() { console.log("test") }
```

However what I noticed, is that when I make a change in my Input prop from the parent and that is updated, I am making my API call once (good) and but then it looks like I am subscribing again ?? so I am having some sort of memory leak.

If in my this.action1() I make a console log, the first time around, it will log once. then if I update my variable or variable2 again, it console logs twice. then thrice. etc.

Is it because my subscription isn't being deleted? So it's calling action1 in multiple subscriptions?

I thought my ngOnDestroy() would take care of that but I guess since the component isn't actually being destroyed but updated, that isn't taking care of it.

So would I move my subscribeMethod to onInit? into my constructor? How do I avoid these excess actions?

Thanks!

Edit I tried moving my subscribeMethod to my ngOnInit and it seems like it fixed the problem, but it is giving me a console log twice. Once with the old subscribe data, once with the new :(

Answer (score 0):

First thing. Angular will automatically call `ngOnChanges` any time one of your inputs change, so you can remove all the code revolving around `simpleChanges`. Generally, you would use code like that if you had some conditional logic regarding to specific inputs. In your case, your condition is true if **any** input changes, so you can just remove that logic altogether.

Second, you're on the right track with your idea of setting your subscription inside `ngOnInit`. You can have something like this:

```
this.deets = this._store.select("details").subscribe(value => {
    if (value) // this.action1()
}
```

I am not sure what you mean with your edit. By definition, you are expecting to call subscribe if the value of your observable changes. Perhaps you can clarify and I'll edit my response.

Comment: Sorry yea you are right about the simple changes. I should have explained better in my dummy data. In my actual project I have about 5 inputs coming in and need to call APIs depending on which was changed.

Comment: Oops. Enter submitted my comment. So by my edit, I meant that I moved my subscribe method to my ngOnInit from my ngOnChanges and it got rid of that memory leak. However, I am having a strange bug(I think it's not really because of this but more my poor routing). But what is happening, is that my old data from my store/subscribe in this.action is being called and then my new data is called. It's only showing my new data but i can see it when I console log. Not a big deal but yea. :) Moving to ngoninit def helped!